# Counting common visited countries

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, unique, array-formulas, counting

This is a simplified post from another question.

Consider this :

[image: Names and visited coutries]

How many visited countries in common does John and Mary have? Same question for John and alfred ? Same question for Alfred and Mary ?

Here is a google sheet to play : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jWAXVGt2_E3fYo8WZSBP1Fp-vg3gYPKlG2ZxC-4SE34/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(countifs($A$2:$A$9,E$1,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))*countifs($A$2:$A$9,$D2,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))))
```

[image]

[image]

As far as I can see there are four correct answers to this question depending how you pose the question, rather like in SQL:

(1) for every instance of person 1 with a country, how many instances of person 2 are there with the same country including duplicates (like a cross join)

(2) for every unique combination of person 1 with a country, how many instances of person 2 with the same country are there (like a left join)

(3) for every unique combination of person 2 with a country, how many instances of person 1 with the same country are there (like a right join)

(4) for each unique combination of person 1 with a country, is there at least one instance of person 2 with the same country (like an inner join)

I have gone for option (1).

The other three formulas should be

```
=ArrayFormula(sum((countifs($A$2:$A$9,E$1,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))>0)*countifs($A$2:$A$9,$D2,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))))

=ArrayFormula(sum(countifs($A$2:$A$9,E$1,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))*(countifs($A$2:$A$9,$D2,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))>0)))

=ArrayFormula(sum((countifs($A$2:$A$9,E$1,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))>0)*(countifs($A$2:$A$9,$D2,$B$2:$B$9,unique($B$2:$B$9))>0)))
```

Comment: Hope that's OK. It counts three times altogether for T1 & T2 above because T1 has category A twice and B once, while T2 has A once and B once.